# Как вставить картинку в сообщение при разметке html в TelegramClient на pyton-teleton

Tags: python, telethon

Не удаётся добавить картинку в сообщение, как это сделать в разметке Html?

```
client.send_message("me", "<b>Жирный</b> <i>Курсив</i> <img src=\"Note.jpg\">", parse_mode="html")
```

Comment: Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь к изображению.

Comment: client.send_message("me", "<b>Жирный</b> <i>Курсив</i> <img src="/content/Ноты - Вечная весна копия.jpg">", parse_mode="html")

Comment: Запускаю на google colab - указал правую ссылку (см. выше) - тоже пишет ошибку: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Старайтесь использовать английский язык для имен переменных, данных и тд. Почему? просто потому... Не используйте в именах своих данных пробелы. Информация должна быть как кинжал, короткой, быстрой и опасно понятной. И в целом ошибка синтаксическая, смотрите внимательно, где-то возможно банально не хватает кавычек например.

Comment: client.send_message("me", "<b>Жирный</b> <i>Курсив</i> <img src=\"/content/Note.jpg\">", parse_mode="html")
       спасибо, с ошибкой разобрался, но картинку всё равно не отправляет.

Comment: Для меня очень мало информации, может кто-то и сможет помочь. Но я не вижу всю картину целиком. Попробуйте обновить ваш вопрос таким образом, что бы он отражал более подробную информацию происходящего.

Comment: Разве телеграм поддерживает тег img в сообщениях? Или это только на ботов распространяется? В списке тегов нет img: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style

Comment: @gil9red, меня тоже смутило.

Comment: Хочу отправлять сообщения с картинкой, как сделать не знаю. Думал через html теги получиться - видимо так не выходит. Может кто подскажет, как реализовать такую задачу?

Comment: @МихаилТаратенко, https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon#doing-stuff, метод send_file

Comment: Это подходит для отправки картинки без текста (не считая подписи), а мне нужно картинку вставлять в середину текста.